# Error when get email activity by using sendgrid API

Tags: sendgrid

I want to get email activity by using Sendgrid API, but it can't filter by a recipient and a date range (this code can get 3 activities, but not filter for parameter: from_email: khoa.do@netlink.vn and not range from date - to date).

Here is the code:

```php
function filter_activity()
    {
        $apiKey = 'SG.xxx';
        $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

        $str_query = "last_event_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2022-02-13T00:00:00.000Z' AND TIMESTAMP '2022-03-13T00:00:00.000Z' AND from_email='khoa.do@netlink.vn'";

        $query_params = array(
            "query" => $str_query,
            "limit"=> 3
        );


        try
        {
            $response = $sg->client->messages()->get(null, $query_params);
            print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
            print_r($response->headers());
            print $response->body() . "\n";
            var_dump($response->body()); die();
        } 
        catch (Exception $ex) 
        {
            echo 'Caught exception: '.  $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I try to use postman, but i has error:

[image]

If anyone know this issue, please let me know how to input correct parameters.
Thank you for your support,

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are including the curly brackets in your timestamp. The documentation shows it like this:

```
curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages?limit=10&query=last_event_time%20BETWEEN%20TIMESTAMP%20%22{start_date}%22%20AND%20TIMESTAMP%20%22{end_date}%22' \
 --header 'authorization: Bearer <<your API key>>'
```

But I think the entire `{start_date}` and `{end_date}` strings should be replaced with the timestamp, not just inside the brackets.

Also, while there can be many parts to the query you are making, they all come as one `query` URL parameter. So, you need to build your query up, then `urlencode` it and set it as the `query` parameter in the URL.

Try it like this:

```php
function filter_activity()
    {

        $apiKey = 'SG.xxx';
        $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

        $start_date = "2022-03-12T00:00:00.000Z";
        $end_date = "2022-03-13T00:00:00.000Z";

        $str = "BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '".$start_date."' AND TIMESTAMP '".$end_date."'";

        $query_params = array(
            "query" => urlencode('last_event_time="' . $str . '" AND from_email="khoa.do@netlink.vn"'),
            "limit"=> 3
        );

        try
        {
            $response = $sg->client->messages()->get(null, $query_params);
            print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
            print_r($response->headers());
            print $response->body() . "\n";
            var_dump(json_decode($response->body(), true)); die();
        } 
        catch (Exception $ex) 
        {
            echo 'Caught exception: '.  $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, I was removed '{}' from date range, it's ok when i paste this link to postman, it can get correct results. I was change code (PHP):

$start_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime("2022-03-10 00:00:00" )); $end_date = date("Y-m-d h:m:s", strtotime("2022-03-14 23:59:59" ));

To:

$start_date = "2022-03-12T00:00:00.000Z"; $end_date = "2022-03-13T00:00:00.000Z";

and removed '{}', but it can not filter by date range and filter from_email (pls take a look at image). Please let me know how to input these parameters in PHP code

Comment: What image do you mean? Can you post the code you are currently using in PHP and the error you are now getting?

Comment: I think I know what happened. The `query` parameter should have the entire query url encoded within it. I've updated my answer. Take a particular look at where I set `$query_params`.

Comment: Do you mean i need encode query_params in this code: $query_params = array("from_email" => "khoa.do@netlink.vn" , "last_event_time" => $str,  "limit"=> 10); ?

Comment: No, check the updated code in the answer above.

Comment: I'm trying with your code, but receive an error:  "error parsing input at line 1, position 18: syntax error: unexpected IDENTIFIER","field":"query". If i encode date range and put to 'last_event_time' parameter; It's not filter by date range and from_email

Comment: The API doesn't take a `last_event_time` parameter. It takes a `query` parameter, and the value of that `query` parameter can include `last_event_time` and also `from_email`. I'm not sure where that parsing error would come from, especially when it says "line 1". Can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: Yes, i've updated my code. Please check again.

Comment: And what is the full error message you get with that code?

Comment: Thank you for your support. I can solve this issue, no need urlencode.

Comment: Oh! The library presumably does the encoding for you. Have you got this working now?

Comment: It's good for me. Thanks for your support.